# Employee taking a time off to climb K2 - How to convince him not to go?

Tags: vacation

Recently, I've approved a timeoff request for three weeks in July submitted by an employee of mine. All I've been told at the time is that he'll be travelling overseas. Just today though, I found out from other employees that this person is heading over to Asia to climb the K2 mountain.

Normally, I wouldn't really care where people go for vacation but after hearing this, I'm genuinely worried about this employee. I'd preferably like to convince him not to go and would like to hear a good way to do this.

Comment: You should sit down, be quiet, and realize that this person's life is their own to live.  Such an undertaking is not done lightly.  This person has probably been preparing and training for *YEARS* to do this.  Your belief that your judgment about how they should live their life is somehow superior to theirs is troubling.  If you were to try to stop them, I'd be very surprised if they didn't quit on the spot.  This is obviously a seriously-considered life goal of theirs.

Comment: Why do you think its not a good idea for him to go?  What do you know of his experience level?  And what do you know the expedition?

Comment: Is your concern motivated by a genuine personal interest in the employee's well-being or by what effect his demise on that trip would have on your business?

Comment: Doesn't it take way longer than 3 weeks to climb K2 ?

Comment: I hope someone with more knowledge of mountaineering will comment, but it seems unlikely that the employee intends a K2 summit attempt. A quick web search suggests typical expeditions take over 2 months, not three weeks. Consider acclimatization and waiting for acceptable weather conditions. There do seem to be treks in the K2 area that could be done in three weeks.

Answer (score 8):

One problem with paying attention to rumors is the risk of getting over-dramatic input. A three week vacation seems unlikely to include a K2 summit attempt, though it could include a trek in the K2 area.

In any case, it is too late to limit your employees' right to engage in high risk activities on their own time. If you need to do so, it should be part of a negotiated contract. You can find samples by looking at contracts for movie actors.

Expect to pay extra to get agreement to any limitations on off-the-job activities. You may miss out on some employees who will not accept your limitations even with extra pay. I wouldn't.

======================================================================

A comment on the question points out the possibility of threatening termination. If you are in an at-will employment situation, you can do that, in theory. In practice, threatening to terminate an employee for vacation activities that do not breach any contract terms would offend many employees, not just that one.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand that you're worried for your employee's safety after hearing that he intends to do something potentially dangerous.  I think that's a natural human reaction, not just for employee and employer, but for anyone.

That being said, this person is not a child.  In particular, they aren't YOUR child.  What they choose to do when they *aren't* on company time isn't your responsibility or really any of your business.

I would suggest you keep your concerns to yourself and trust that your employee is aware of any dangers he is preparing to undertake on his planned vacation.  Hope for the best and try not to worry so much.